# Variable that keeps track of line number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a bit confused on this. So I have to increment a variable that keeps track of the line number every time my program reads a line of input.

```
while True:
    line = input()
    line_variable = line + 1
```

Not sure if that is how you do it since I am just winging it. Thanks!
I'm using Python.

Comment: line_variable = line + 1 will throw an error TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects. Since line is a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your `line` variable is a string that is obtained as a result of someone typing something into `input()`. Instead you want something like:

```
line_num = 0
while True:
    line = input()
    line_num += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This code uses a generator function to repeatedly prompt for input (use `raw_input()` for Py2, just `input()` for Py3), then `enumerate` to give us ever-increasing line numbers:

```
def input_gen():
    while True:
        yield raw_input('> ')

for lineno, data in enumerate(input_gen()):
    if not data:
        break
    print(lineno, data)
```

Here is some sample output:

```
> lksjdf
(0, 'lksjdf')
> lkjdsf
(1, 'lkjdsf')
> lksjdf
(2, 'lksjdf')
> lsdkjf
(3, 'lsdkjf')
>
```

This code ends when you enter a blank line - you can change this exit condition to whatever you like.